# Saving Video Data To File From POST request InputStream in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, post, inputstream, outputstream, httplistener

I am having trouble quite figuring out how to save video data sent to me via a HttpListener in PowerShell.  I have the following which I believe is just sending it back to the requester but I'm having trouble just saving it into an MP4 file.

```
    $req = $request
    $body = $req.InputStream
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader ($body, $req.ContentEncoding)
    $msg = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()

    [byte[]] $buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($msg)
    $res.ContentLength64 = $buffer.Length
    $res.StatusCode = 200
    $res.OutputStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
    $res.Close()
```

Thank you for your time eveyrone!

Update:

I have been able to make files with this, though for some reason in examples they're using 8192 sized byte but PowerShell says it's too big. With this I get zero length files, no errors that I can tell.

```
    $path = "c:\matthew3.mp4"
    $file = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $path,CreateNew

    [byte]$bytes = 255

    [int]$bytes_read = 0

    while ( $bytes_read = $request.InputStream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.length) > 0 ) 

    {

        $file.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes_read)

    }
```

Actually I did get an error:

```
Exception calling "GetBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Array cannot be null.
Parameter name: chars"
At line:45 char:1
+ $buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($content)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Exception calling "Write" with "3" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer"
At line:47 char:1
+ $response.OutputStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
```

Comment: Is it really encoded in UTF8? I would expect it's raw, so `[Text.Encoding]::Default` should be used. Anyway, what the trouble is?

Comment: I'm trying this to save it to a file, I updated the post.  I get a zero length file though.  It's not complaining about anything as far as I can tell.  I'm using the Chrome tool Postman to send the binary.  Would a video file just be POSTed as raw?

Comment: Depending on how Postman API works, it could be raw as it's most effective for binary data. Or it could be JSON-stringified. However, judging by the error messages you've added, nothing is received at all. Try debugging the code line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main developer for our company Nick pointed me in the right direction here.

The main thing is that for the FileStream object I needed to add the Write flag, and use the CopyTo method on the InputStream and then close both of them:

```
        $file = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $path,CreateNew,Write

        $context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo($file)

        $file.Close()

        $context.Request.InputStream.Close()
```